# SAS regular expression in PROC SQL - The end in a String

Tags: regex, sas

Im am working to delete the word "JR" from a variable string in a SAS table. Herre is my code :

```
proc sql;
    create table admin_name_clean as
        select distinct
        admin_name,
        prxchange('s/\sJR$//',-1, admin_name) as name_clean

        from admins
;
quit;
```

For exemple, admin_name contains SCHIL, ROB B JR. I want to have SCHIL, ROB B in name_clean, but I have always SCHIL, ROB B JR.

If I try do this in a data proc, it work fine !!!

```
data _null_;
    a="SCHIL, ROB B JR";
    b=prxchange('s/\sJR$//',-1, a);
    put b;
;
run;
```

Is there a specification in the PROC SQL that I am missing ?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try `\bJR\b` or `\sJR\s` as `\sJR$` matches a whitespace char and `JR` at the end of the string.

Comment: @The fourth bird : But the string is not endding with a space.

Comment: Then try it like this `\sJR\b` https://regex101.com/r/TS8FPH/1 or `\sJR(?!\S)`

Comment: Thank you for the link! It is interresting. But sorry, it is not what I want. JR must be at the end of the string. I have said it in the title of my question.

Comment: SAS character variables are fixed length and padded with spaces. `prxchange('s/\sJR$//',-1, trim(admin_name)) `

Comment: @Tom Yes that's it! Thank you!!!